# Question on calculus

Tags: calculus

I want to compute
$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3} + n^{2}\cos\left(n\right)}.\quad}$
Can anyone help me or give a hint?

Comment: I don't see how. Converges, yes. If you had $\cos (\pi n)$ maybe something could be done

Comment: What can we do with cos(pi n)?

Comment: And why is it converging?

Comment: $\cos(\pi n)$ for integer $n$ is just $(-1)^n$ which is way easier to work with than the cosine of integer values.

Comment: It converges since each term $\frac{1}{n^3+n^2cos(n)}$ is less than $\frac{1}{(n-1)^3}$, which converges by the p-series test, so by the direct comparison test your series converges.

Comment: but your fraction is different from mine

Comment: oh i see, it still works by p test

Comment: but how to compute it?

Comment: Numerically, using a software package like Mathematica or Sage.

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for an answer.*

I do not think that a closed form of the summation could be found.

Using the same argument as user125261 in his/her comment, you can write 
$$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3+n^2}\lt\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3+n^2\cos(n)}\lt \sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3-n^2}$$ that is to say $$\frac{3 \pi ^2-29}{18}\lt\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3+n^2\cos(n)}\lt \frac{61-6 \pi ^2}{36}\approx 0.0495104$$ Now, computing partial sums, one could get the following results for $$S_p=\sum_{n=4}^{p}\frac{1}{n^3+n^2\cos(n)}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 100 & 0.0419069 \\
 200 & 0.0419439 \\
 300 & 0.0419508 \\
 400 & 0.0419533 \\
 500 & 0.0419544 \\
 600 & 0.041955 \\
 700 & 0.0419553 \\
 800 & 0.0419556 \\
 900 & 0.0419558 \\
 1000 & 0.0419559
\end{array}
\right)$$ which do not show a very fast convergence (this was done using Excel).

Comment: I tried it out on Python and for $p = 1000000$, $S_p = 0.04195636889897616$. Maybe for higher and higher values of $p$ it would just be around $S_p \approx 0.04196$

Edit: Tried for $S_0 = 10000000$ and $S_p$ still has the same answer, so either it converges to that number or it's just a limitation of Python. Either way I wouldn't try a higher value of $p$ as it might crash my computer.

Comment: @Aldon. Thanks for the info. I tried also and arrived to $\approx 0.041956368900332$